# Multiple #includes, different functions, same name: How to differentiate them?

Tags: c++, winsock2

Seem to be having a bit of an issue here, and this is probably a really dumb question:

```
#incude <thread>
```

and

```
#include <winsock2.h>
```

both contain a function called bind().
I want to call this winsock2 bind:

```
bind(listenerSocket._internalCustomSocket, (sockaddr*)&listenerSocket._peer, listenerSocket._peerLength)
```

Where listenerSocket is my custom socket class that looks like this:

```
class CustomSocket
{
public:
    CustomSocket(int port);
    ~CustomSocket();

    SOCKET OpenSocket(Listener* host);

    int _port;
    SOCKET _internalCustomSocket;
    sockaddr_in _peer;
    int _peerLength;

};
```

However, it instead defaults to using the  bind() which looks like

```
_NODISCARD inline _Binder<_Unforced, _Fx, _Types...> bind(_Fx&& _Func, _Types&&... _Args)
```

How do I specify which one it is that I want to call?

The only solution I've found so far is to not include the  include

Comment: Do you happen to have `using namespace std;` in your program? If so, try removing it. Alternatively, using `::bind` should work.

Comment: Yes, would that be the source of the problem?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat will try that now

Answer (score 0):

First of all, eliminate any use of `using namespace std;` from your code.  That will just mess things up.

Then, to access Winsock's bind, you can write:

```
::bind (...);
```

And to access the version of `bind` in the STL, you can write:

```
std::bind (...);
```

And now you know what namespaces are for.

Comment: If OP removes `using namespace std;`, then `bind` can be used instead of `::bind`.